# I have a webservice in a private network. How put that accessible to all users?

Tags: web-services, private, public

in my work, i have to use one werbservice which is another computer in the network of my work.

In this way, I can not access if I'm not in the network. What i can do to can get access outside of network? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to setup portforwarding in your router/firewall.

Answer (score 2):

And also you have to setup virtual host in router setting.And will be helpful for you if you use no-ip if your router have dynamic ip